# "Silent" errors in .ADP with SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, sql-server-express, adp

I have an adp project in MS Access 2003 with an SQL Server Express 2008 as backend.

Everything works fine, except when there is an error on the SQL side, e.g. duplicate indices. the current dataset just doesn’t get updated/inserted, no error message whats-o-ever, but I know it’s not updated, because if I do a select on the server I still get the old data.

How can I "unsilence" the errors? is there some hidden option, or is it a problem that only occurs with access 2003 + sql server 2008?

Any help appreciated as I haven’t found anything helpful on the net yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is actually a very obscure bug in ms access. i found the solution on eggheadcafe, which works perfectly. now the errors pop up too often xD

> SO... if the default language for
>   non-unicode programs is for example
>   Japanese but the selected language for
>   standards and formats is Arabic, the
>   ADP project won't display any database
>   error messages whatsoever.  Try, for
>   example, to save a record with a
>   duplicate primary key.  Nothing will
>   happen, but you won't know why.
>
> HOW TO SOLVE: Given the above, the
>   language selected for "Standards and
>   Formats" MUST ALWAYS be identical to
>   the one selected for non-unicode
>   programs.  Japanese and Japanese,
>   Chinese and Chinese, Hebrew and
>   Hebrew, Arabic and Arabic, etc, which
>   in turn makes the operating system's
>   option to define them separately
>   rather useless...

quoted from
http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/34687624/access-2003-bug-adp-erro.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [Handling Errors and Messages in ADO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa905919(SQL.80).aspx). You may find [dbFailOnError](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb243015.aspx) to be relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the IGNORE_DUP_KEY option is set on the index that should catch the constraint.